# Will the history be gone after rebasing in git

Tags: git, version-control

Suppose i have master branch with three commits

```
A--B----C
```

I create new branch `dev` and create 3 commits there

```
A--B----C------C1------C2
         \
          E---F----G
```

now i merge with master like this

`git merge dev --squash`

Now i think the new diagram is like this but not sure

```
A--B----C------C1------C2--------M----
         \                      /    
          E---F----G-----------/
```

After again i need to merge `dev` branch with master to get commmit c1 and c2

so it will be like this

```
A--B----C------C1------C2--------M----
         \                      / \   
          E---F----G-----------/----m2 ---H--I
```

`dev` and `master` will go in parallel

I want to know that

1. Will the individual commit history will be there in dev branch after squasing for commits E F G
2. I want to know what will be the diagram if i ahve to use rebase instead of merge where both branches should go in parallel
3. If answer to first question is yes then will individual history commits be gone if i use rebase command

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me re-draw the second diagram with some labels:

```
A--B--C-----C1----C2    <-- master
       \
        E--F----G    <-- dev
```

(I assume `C1` and `C2` just represent a few more commits that occurred on `master` while `E`, `F`, and `G` were being added to `dev`).

If you now are on `master` and run `git merge dev --squash` (and then commit the result: `--squash` suppresses the final commit step), you get *this*, which is very different from what you drew:

```
A--B--C-----C1----C2---M    <-- master
       \
        E--F----G    <-- dev
```

You will get what you drew if you run `git merge` *without* `--squash`.  The `--squash` flag will, to quote the documentation:

> Produce the working tree and index state as if a real merge
>              happened (except for the merge information), but **do not actually
>              make a commit** or move the HEAD, **nor record $GIT_DIR/MERGE_HEAD** to
>              cause the next git commit command to create a merge commit.

In other words, a squash merge is not a merge at all (this is why I have, er, "issues" with some of git's terminology :-) ... some checkouts are checkouts, and some are not; some merges are merges, and some are not; branches are just branch tips except when they're not, and so on!).  A "squash merge" does use the underlying merge code to figure out what the contents of the next commit should be, but if and when you make the actual commit (the one labeled `M` above), it's just an ordinary non-merge commit, that takes the work done—the changes made—in commits `E` through `G` and copies those changes into whatever was the latest version in `C2`.  Think of it as "someone sends you a diff, comparing version `C` to version `G`, and then you manually insert all those changes into version `C2` and commit that (which should probably be called `C3` but we called it `M` instead)".

---

If you want a real merge, do a merge *without* `--squash`.  That will in fact give you what you drew, which I will re-draw here:

```
A--B--C-----C1----C2---M    <-- master
       \              /
        E--F----G----/      <-- dev
```

(The label `dev` still points to commit `G`.)

Next, if you want to pick up the changes in `C1` and `C2` and put them on `dev`, you can do one of two things:

```
git checkout dev && git merge master
```

or:

```
git checkout dev && git merge --no-ff master
```

The difference here is whether you get the commit `m2` you drew.  Without `--no-ff`, git observes that the merge of `dev` and `master` produces commit `M`, and just moves the `dev` label to point to `M`:

```
A--B--C-----C1----C2---M    <-- dev, master
       \              /
        E--F----G----/
```

But with `--no-ff`, the merge must produce a new, different merge commit (the same tree, but a different commit nonetheless, with different parent-age):

```
A--B--C-----C1----C2---M    <-- master
       \               X
        E--F----G------m2   <-- dev
```

Here merge `M` has `C2` as its first parent and `G` as its second parent.  This indicates that it's a merge of `G2` (the "non-first" parent) into `master` (the first parent).  Merge `m2`, on the other hand, has `G` as its first parent and `C2` as its second parent.

In other words, the trees (working directories) are the same, the *set* (list-ignoring-order) of parents is the same, and even the commit messages and timestamps could be the same: but the *order* of the parents is different, and that alone is sufficient to guarantee that these will be different commits.

---

The *title* of your question is about rebasing, rather than merging.  Rebase is a different operation entirely.  Let's say you're on branch `dev` and run `git rebase master`.

To do a rebase, what git does is (in essence—there's some optimization applied, and some corner cases with merge commits) simply "cherry pick" each commit along some branch, and apply those "cherries" to some other branch.  Let's go back to the first diagram:

```
A--B--C--C1--C2    <-- master
       \
        E--F--G    <-- dev
```

The idea here is to "pick" the commits `E`, then `F`, then `G` and apply them in sequence.  Let's start by copying `E` to `E'`, applied on top of `C2`:

```
                E'
               /
A--B--C--C1--C2    <-- master
       \
        E--F--G    <-- dev
```

Next we copy `F` to `F'` like this:

```
                E'--F'
               /
A--B--C--C1--C2    <-- master
       \
        E--F--G    <-- dev
```

There's one more commit to copy, `G` to `G'`:

```
                E'--F'--G'
               /
A--B--C--C1--C2    <-- master
       \
        E--F--G    <-- dev
```

We're all done except for one thing: we need a label for the new chain of commits.  Let's call it `dev`!  Oops, wait, we already have a label `dev`.  Well, let's just peel off the old `dev` label, and paste it on the new `G'`:

```
                E'--F'--G'   <-- dev
               /
A--B--C--C1--C2    <-- master
       \
        E--F--G
```

Voila, `git rebase` is done.  That's what it does: copy the old commits to new ones.

What happens to the old ones?  Well, they're what I call "abandoned".  They are still there in your repository, but the only labels for them are stored only in the "reflogs".  The reflog entries will keep them around for a default expiration timeout of 30 days or so.  (It's configurable, and there are actually two different timeouts, but it's best to just think of this as "a month or so".)  Thus, in about a month, git will garbage-collect the abandoned commits.

Sometimes rebasing is "bad", in that it creates more work for other people who are sharing your git repo (either directly, or more likely, at some central repository you push your work up to).  Suppose someone else has commits `E` through `G`, and they did more work and made commit `H` for instance on top of `G`.  Then you go and copy `E` through `G`, and abandon the original `E` through `G`.  You've now made *their* work, commit `H`, require yet more work: they may have to rebase their `H` on your `G'`, for instance.

If nobody else has your commits `E` through `G`, you can be sure that you have not made any extra work for the nonexistent other people.  A rebase will only affect *you*, so most of the "bad" goes away.

---

In the end, there's no single answer to rebase vs merge (and if merge, whether and when to use `--no-ff`) vs "squash merge and abandon original development chain" vs whatever-else-you-can-come-up-with.  The whole idea of making commits in git, and manipulating them with merges and cherry-picking and rebasing and so on, is to make it easier to maintain the *work*.  All the fiddling with commit graphs is pointless unless it makes maintaining the real work easier.

Comment: thanks torek , i think i now have to read all your answer for git :). The issue i am facing is that other coders are squashing all commits so that i dont get how they chnage the file  and i am trying to find the way whether i can get those individual commits from squashed ocmmits or not. i wanted to know what theya re doing so that i can show it to manager

Comment: If they are squashing merges and just committing the result, then that commit will only have one parent and thus it will not be possible to point it back to the squashed commits. Unless you know what commits where squashed there would be no way to point back to them through git.

Comment: The `--squash` command has that purpouse. If you are in a situation where you have commits in a branch, but you want all those changes to appear just as a single new change in another branch then you do a squash. This is very similar to what can be achieved with `rebase`, perhaps from there the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

well I will try to explain...

when you rebase master on top of dev:

```
A--B----C-----E---F----G-------------C1------C2
         \                      /    
          E---F----G-----------/
```

after it you can just pull from `master` to dev without conflicts

when you rebase dev on top of master:

```
A--B----C------C1------C2----
         \                        
          ----C1------C2------E---F----G-----------
```

after it you can just pull from `dev` to master without conflicts

sure second variant when you rebase `dev` branch instead of changing `master` is much better...